# LINQ for XML, having trouble reading in multiple elements of varying occurences

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

Let's say I have the following XML file below.  My question is, how to I account for a different number of name elements (child of environment element) when querying using LINQ.  I can read the file and even query when there are the same number of name elements (for example, they all have 3).  My goal is to populate an object that has a list caled environment with the names in the XML file.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
     <database type="prod">
    <name>DB1</name>
    <server>
        <name>prodserver.net</name>
    </server>
    <connection>
        <name>u1</name>
        <password>b1</password>
    </connection>
    <environment>
        <name>test1</name>
        <name>test2</name>
        <name>test3</name>
    </environment>
</database>
      <database type="dev">
    <name>DB2</name>
    <server>
        <name>devserver.net</name>
    </server>
    <connection>
        <name>u11</name>
        <password>b11</password>
    </connection>
    <environment>
        <name>test1</name>
        <name>test2</name>
        <name>test3</name>
                          <name>test4</name>
                          <name>test5</name>
    </environment>
</database>
```

Or maybe to make it even easier, let's say I have the following

```
  <student name="A" class="1">
<classes>
  Math
</classes>
</student>  
<student name="B" class="2">
  <classes>
   Programming
  </classes>
</student>
```

And I run the following code:

```
var students = doc.Root
                          .Elements("student")
                          .Select(x => new Student
                          {
                              Name = (string)x.Attribute("name"),
                              Class = (string)x.Attribute("class"),
                              Type = (string)x.Elements("classes").Single().Value
                          })
                          .ToList();
```

It works fine, but when I add one more classes element, it breaks:

```
  <student name="A" class="1">
<classes>
  Math
</classes>
<classes>
  Java
</classes>
</student>  
<student name="B" class="2">
  <classes>
    Programming
  </classes>
</student>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean... assuming you have (say) an `Environment` type with a constructor accepting a `List<string>` as the names, you'd use:

```
// If element is the <environment> element
Environment = new Environment(element.Elements("name")
                                     .Select(x => x.Value)
                                     .ToList());
```

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question as it was a bit vague, I've added a simpler example...

Comment: @PaulDimech: Well you're currently calling `Single()`, which suggests you want a single value - and your `Class` property type is just a single value. How do you *want* to handle that in your `Student` code? Fundamentally you've got to have a model which supports multiple values...

Comment: Sorry, I tried to draw up a quick example, if I had a class that contained List<string> classes and I wanted to populate it based on the number of elements.  The above example wasn't good as it has a class attribute and a class element and the Type type (again poor choice) isn't an array or list.

Comment: @PaulDimech: Don't draw up a *quick* example. Draw up a *good* example. I've shown you how you could construct an `Environment` object which required a `List<string>` for the names - have you looked carefully at that example? It certainly *sounds* like it does what you need...

Comment: Hi Jon,

Thanks, much appreciated, it worked well.  Sorry for the poor example and follow up poor example, I'll make sure to explain more and keep it simple and complete.  I added the following which worked perfectly:

  
Type = x.Elements("classes").Select(y => y.Value).ToList()